# inject bean reference into a Quartz job in Spring?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, inject

I managed to configure and schedule a Quartz  job using JobStoreTX persistent store in Spring. I do not use Spring's Quartz jobs, because I need to schedule them dynamically, at run time, and all examples of integrating Spring with Quartz that i found were hard-coding the shcedules in the Spring config files... Anyway, here is how I schedule the job:

```
JobDetail emailJob = JobBuilder.newJob(EMailJob.class)
.withIdentity("someJobKey", "immediateEmailsGroup")
.storeDurably()
.build();

SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger() 
.withIdentity("someTriggerKey", "immediateEmailsGroup")
.startAt(fireTime)
.build();

// pass initialization parameters into the job
emailJob.getJobDataMap().put(NotificationConstants.MESSAGE_PARAMETERS_KEY,       messageParameters);
emailJob.getJobDataMap().put(NotificationConstants.RECIPIENT_KEY, recipient);

if (!scheduler.checkExists(jobKey) && scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey) != null)     {                                       
// schedule the job to run
Date scheduleTime1 = scheduler.scheduleJob(emailJob, trigger);
}
```

The EMailJob is a simple job that is sending e-mail using the Spring's JavaMailSenderImpl class.

```
public class EMailJob implements Job {
@Autowired
private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl;

    public EMailJob() {
    }
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
       throws JobExecutionException {
   ....
    try {
        mailSenderImpl.send(mimeMessage);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        ....
        throw new JobExecutionException("EMailJob failed: " +  jobKey.getName(), e);
    }

    logger.info("EMailJob finished OK");

}
```

The problem is that I need to get a reference to an instance of this class (JavaMailSenderImpl)  in my EMailJob class. When I try to inject it like this:

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl;
```

it is not injected - the reference is NULL. I'm assuming this is happening because it is not  Spring who instantiates the EMailJob class, but Quartz, and Quartz does not know anything about dependency injection...

So, is there some way to force this injection to happen?

thanks!

Update 1:
@Aaron:
here is a relevant part of the stacktrace from the startup, which is showing the the EMailJob was instantiated twice:

```
2011-08-15 14:16:38,687 [main] INFO     org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler#0' is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2011-08-15 14:16:38,734 [main] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1328c7a: defining beans [...]; root of factory hierarchy
2011-08-15 14:16:39,734 [main] INFO  com.cambridgedata.notifications.EMailJob - EMailJob() -  initializing ...
2011-08-15 14:16:39,937 [main] INFO  org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor -   Validated configuration attributes
2011-08-15 14:16:40,078 [main] INFO  org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Validated configuration attributes
2011-08-15 14:16:40,296 [main] INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator - Executing SQL script from class path resource ...
2011-08-15 14:17:14,031 [main] INFO  com.mchange.v2.log.MLog - MLog clients using log4j logging.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,109 [main] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.1 [built 15-March-2007 01:32:31; debug? true; trace: 10]
2011-08-15 14:17:14,171 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2011-08-15 14:17:14,171 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.0.1 created.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Using thread monitor-based data access locking (synchronization).
2011-08-15 14:17:14,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - JobStoreTX initialized.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.0.1) 'NotificationsScheduler' with instanceId  'NON_CLUSTERED'
 Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
   NOT STARTED.
 Currently in standby mode.
 Number of jobs executed: 0
 Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 3 threads.
 Using job-store 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.

2011-08-15 14:17:14,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'NotificationsScheduler' initialized from the specified file : 'spring/quartz.properties' from the class resource path.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.0.1
2011-08-15 14:17:14,234 [main] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 2sajb28h1lcabf28k3nr1|13af084, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2sajb28h1lcabf28k3nr1|13af084, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 50, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/2010rewrite2, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 5, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 120, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> select 0 from dual, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2011-08-15 14:17:14,312 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Freed 0 triggers from 'acquired' / 'blocked' state.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,328 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Recovering 0 jobs that were in-progress at the time of the last shut-down.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,328 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Recovery complete.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,328 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Removed 0 'complete' triggers.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,328 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Removed 0 stale fired job entries.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,328 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler NotificationsScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2011-08-15 14:17:14,515 [NotificationsScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] INFO  com.cambridgedata.notifications.EMailJob - EMailJob() -  initializing ...
```

thanks!

Update #2: @Ryan:

I tried to use the SpringBeanJobFactory as following:

```
    <bean id="jobFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory">
</bean>

<bean id="schedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:spring/quartz.properties"/>
        <property name="jobFactory" ref="jobFactoryBean"/>
</bean>
```

And I have modified my main class to get Scheduler from this factory, instead of Quartz':

```
    @PostConstruct
public void initNotificationScheduler() {
    try {
        //sf = new StdSchedulerFactory("spring/quartz.properties");
        //scheduler = sf.getScheduler();

        scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
            ....
```

But when I run the app - get errors, see below. Here is the stacktrace from Spring startup . Seems like the Scheduler itself is created fine, but the error comes when it is trying to instantiate my EMailJob:

```
2011-08-15 21:49:42,968 [main] INFO  org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Loading Quartz config from [class path resource [spring/quartz.properties]]
2011-08-15 21:49:43,031 [main] INFO  com.mchange.v2.log.MLog - MLog clients using log4j logging.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,109 [main] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.1 [built 15-March-2007 01:32:31; debug? true; trace: 10]
2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.0.1 created.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Using thread monitor-based data access locking (synchronization).
2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - JobStoreTX initialized.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.0.1) 'schedulerFactoryBean' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
 Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
 NOT STARTED.
 Currently in standby mode.
 Number of jobs executed: 0
 Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 3 threads.
 Using job-store 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.

2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'schedulerFactoryBean' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.0.1
2011-08-15 21:49:43,187 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@566633
2011-08-15 21:49:43,265 [main] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 1hge13f8h1lsg7py1rg0iu0|1956391, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hge13f8h1lsg7py1rg0iu0|1956391, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 50, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/2010rewrite2, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 5, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 120, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> select 0 from dual, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> true, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
2011-08-15 21:49:43,343 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Freed 0 triggers from 'acquired' / 'blocked' state.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,359 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Recovering 0 jobs that were in-progress at the time of the last shut-down.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,359 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Recovery complete.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,359 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Removed 0 'complete' triggers.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,359 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Removed 0 stale fired job entries.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,359 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler schedulerFactoryBean_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2011-08-15 21:49:43,562 [schedulerFactoryBean_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'immediateEmailsGroup.DEFAULT.jobFor_1000new1'
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class  'com.cambridgedata.notifications.EMailJob' -  [See nested exception:  java.lang.AbstractMethodError:  org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory.newJob(Lorg/quartz/spi/TriggerFiredBundle;Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;)Lorg/quartz/Job;]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:141)
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:381)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory.newJob(Lorg/quartz/spi/TriggerFiredBundle;Lorg/quartz/Scheduler;)Lorg/quartz/Job;
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:134)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 141):

You can use this `SpringBeanJobFactory` to automatically autowire quartz objects using spring:

```
import org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory;
 
public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements
    ApplicationContextAware {
 
    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
 
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }
 
    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

Then, attach it to your `SchedulerBean` (in this case, with Java-config):

```
@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

    ...

    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    ...

    return quartzScheduler;
}
```

Working for me, using spring-3.2.1 and quartz-2.1.6.

Check out the complete gist [here](https://gist.github.com/jelies/5085593).

I found the solution in this [blog post](http://www.btmatthews.com/blog/2011/inject-application-context+dependencies-in-quartz-job-beans.html)

Comment: Thanks - this saved me days!  Why hasn't Spring provided this OOB. This is the very basic requirement for using Quartz in Spring.

Comment: great solution, but anyone has any idea why is AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory marked as "transient"? AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory does not seem to be serialized anyway, so neither will beanFactory ever need to be serialized

Comment: I don't know how this works, because, honestly, it looks like magic to me.  I made a few minor changes to these classes to suit it to my environment, but other than that it Just Worked™.  I only wish an out-of-the-box solution existed, because having to schedule/reschedule tasks during runtime is such a common and frequent thing.  It's like creating a 2014 car that doesn't have adjustable seats, leaving you wondering what the car manufacturer was thinking when such an obvious requirement was left out.

Comment: I'm getting hibernate lazyinit exception saying no session in the quartz job, any idea how to fix ?

Comment: This is a great answer, but it doesn't call @PostConstruct methods for the jobs.  That can be fixed by adding `beanFactory.initializeBean(job, "job");` after the `beanFactory.autowireBean(job)` call in `AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory`.

Comment: Can anyone explain how this works behind the scenes? It's too much of magic for me to understand :-)

Comment: A bit late but has anyone tried JDBC with this? A default RAM store works fine for me, but as soon as I switch to JDBC I get "No qualifying bean of type" exception

Comment: If your quartz is still not able to find the beans, here is my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990767/inject-bean-reference-into-a-quartz-job-in-spring/48348291#48348291

Comment: Isn't this missing `super.setApplicationContext(context);` in `setApplicationContext()`?

Answer (score 58):

I just put `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` as first line of my `Job.execute(JobExecutionContext context)` method.

Comment: This is the real solution. Tested with Spring 3.2.4.RELEASE and Quartz 2.2.0. ;)

Comment: It works great and is simple enough for me. Thanks !

Comment: simple answer, easy to implement.

Comment: It worked fine. it is working with spring 3.2.11.RELEASE and quartz 1.8.6, i will upgrade to quartz 2.x to check it.

Comment: The problem with this is that it couples your job with the spring framework in a very hard way.How much of a problem that ultimately is...that is debatable.

Comment: @demaniak, I don't see a big difference between my answer and the most popular answer - I do the same(`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` vs `beanFactory.autowireBean(job);`), but with less of code. Or maybe i miss something?

Comment: @msangel - well, both WILL work, but the problem with using SpringBeanAutowiringSupport in your Quartz job, is that the job instance now needs to KNOW about Spring, which goes against the whole idea of IoC (dep injection). If you now for example need to use CDI, all your quartz jobs will need to be adjusted, instead of just the one job factory.

Comment: Oh, and on the note of CDI - bringing CDI into the actual Quartz job basically impossible last time I tried it - I HAD to do some job factory magic to make CDI work with quartz.

Comment: This did not work for me in a unit test since it searches for a web application context. I had to use the answer from @jelies

Comment: This solution does not work with spring 4.1.4 and Quartz 2.2.1

Comment: Amazing. 2 hours wasted reading rubbish spring documentation and examples. This is THE correct solution for the asked question.

Comment: I had this problem too and I tried this solution. It's working BUT it creates a new instance instead of using already created one (default singleton). Anyway you can pass anything to your job by using scheduler.getContext().put("objectName", object);

Answer (score 13):

Same problem has been resolved in [LINK](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?53160-Spring-s-Quartz-Integration-how-to-schedule-new-jobs-programmatically):

I could found other option from post on the Spring forum that you can pass a reference to the Spring application context via the SchedulerFactoryBean. Like the example shown below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
<propertyy name="triggers">
    <list>
        <ref bean="simpleTrigger"/>
            </list>
    </property>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
        <value>applicationContext</value>
</property>
```

Then using below code in your job class you can get the applicationContext and get whatever bean you want.

```
appCtx = (ApplicationContext)context.getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContextSchedulerContextKey");
```

Hope it helps.
You can get more information from  [Mark Mclaren'sBlog](http://blog.mark-mclaren.info/2007/06/accessing-spring-beans-from-quartz-jobs_1652.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Rippon! After much trying and failing, I have used a very similar approach that you suggested : I have not used the applicationContextSchedulerContextKey property and application context, but I used the 'code'<property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
          <map>
              <entry key="mailService" value-ref="mailService" />
          </map>
      </property>

Answer (score 8):

You're right in your assumption about Spring vs. Quartz instantiating the class. However, Spring provides some classes that let you do some primitive dependency injection in Quartz. Check out [SchedulerFactoryBean.setJobFactory()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setJobFactory%28org.quartz.spi.JobFactory%29) along with the [SpringBeanJobFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SpringBeanJobFactory.html). Essentially, by using the SpringBeanJobFactory, you enable dependency injection on all Job properties, but only for values that are in the Quartz [scheduler context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html#setSchedulerContextAsMap%28java.util.Map%29) or the [job data map](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/1.8.1/index.html). I don't know what all DI styles it supports (constructor, annotation, setter...) but I do know it supports setter injection.

Comment: Hi, Ryan,thanks for your suggestions. Do you mean that I would have to use the SpringBeanFactoryJob, along with pre-configured Triggers and jobs that extend QuartzJobBean in order to enable dependency injection? The problem with this approach is that the triggers are defined statically in the Spring's config files, where I need to be able to define triggers with dynamic schedules at run time... See my next answer below for more details - not enough space in the comments area...

Comment: @Marina: No, that's not how it works. Use SpringBeanJobFactory, and do it the way you want to do it. It will just work. Also, don't post an answer that's just an update to your question. Edit your question instead.

Comment: sorry, I just noticed your comment! I will try it out as you suggest and  will let you know the results. Thanks for your help!Oh, and I will try to edit my question instead of answering...

Answer (score 7):

for all who will try this in the future.

org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean
supplies map of objects and those objects may be spring beans.

define smth like

```
<bean name="myJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass"
        value="my.cool.class.myCoolJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="myBean" value-ref="myBean" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and then, inside

```
public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
```

call `myBean = (myBean) context.getMergedJobDataMap().get("myBean");`
and you all set.
I know, it looks ugly, but as a workaround it works

Comment: IMHO I feel this solution more clean and "natural" than trying to add the autowiring capability to the quartz jobs, so I don't think it's a work around.

Answer (score 6):

```
ApplicationContext springContext =

WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ContextLoaderListener .getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getServletContext());

Bean bean = (Bean) springContext.getBean("beanName");

bean.method();
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, Rippon!
I have finally got this working too, after  many struggles, and my solution is very close to what you suggested! The key was to make my own Job to extend QuartzJobBean, and to use the schedulerContextAsMap.

I did get away without specifying the applicationContextSchedulerContextKey property - it worked without it for me.

For the benefit of others, here is the final configuration that has worked for me:

```
    <bean id="quartzScheduler"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:spring/quartz.properties"/>
        <property name="jobFactory">
            <bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="mailService" value-ref="mailService" />
            </map>
        </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jobTriggerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetBeanName">
        <idref local="jobTrigger" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jobTrigger"   class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean"
    scope="prototype">
      <property name="group" value="myJobs" />
      <property name="description" value="myDescription" />
      <property name="repeatCount" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobDetailFactory"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetBeanName">
        <idref local="jobDetail" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean"
scope="prototype">
<property name="jobClass" value="com.cambridgedata.notifications.EMailJob" />
<property name="volatility" value="false" />
<property name="durability" value="false" />
<property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" />
</bean> 
<bean id="notificationScheduler"   class="com.cambridgedata.notifications.NotificationScheduler">
    <constructor-arg ref="quartzScheduler" />
    <constructor-arg ref="jobDetailFactory" />
    <constructor-arg ref="jobTriggerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Notice that the 'mailService" bean is my own service bean, managed by Spring. I was able to access it in my Job as following:

```
    public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
    throws JobExecutionException {

    logger.info("EMailJob started ...");
    ....
    SchedulerContext schedulerContext = null;
    try {
        schedulerContext = context.getScheduler().getContext();
    } catch (SchedulerException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    MailService mailService = (MailService)schedulerContext.get("mailService");
    ....
```

And this configuration also allowed me to dynamically scheduler jobs, by using factories to  get Triggers and JobDetails and setting required parameters on them programmatically:

```
    public NotificationScheduler(final Scheduler scheduler,
        final ObjectFactory<JobDetail> jobDetailFactory,
        final ObjectFactory<SimpleTrigger> jobTriggerFactory) {
    this.scheduler = scheduler;
    this.jobDetailFactory = jobDetailFactory;
    this.jobTriggerFactory = jobTriggerFactory;
           ...
        // create a trigger
        SimpleTrigger trigger = jobTriggerFactory.getObject();
        trigger.setRepeatInterval(0L);
    trigger.setStartTime(new Date());

    // create job details
    JobDetail emailJob = jobDetailFactory.getObject();

    emailJob.setName("new name");
    emailJob.setGroup("immediateEmailsGroup");
            ...
```

Thanks a lot again to everybody who helped,

Marina

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to set the spring bean  in the Job Data Map and then retrieve the bean in the job class, for instance

```
// the class sets the configures the MyJob class 
    SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
    Date startTime = DateBuilder.nextGivenSecondDate(null, 15);
    JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();
    job.getJobDataMap().put("processDataDAO", processDataDAO);
```

`

```
 // this is MyJob Class
    ProcessDataDAO processDataDAO = (ProcessDataDAO) jec.getMergedJobDataMap().get("processDataDAO");
```

Comment: considering that job data is stored as blob (when using db persistence) this could lead to db performance issues (Imagine data is really huge)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what the code looks like with @Component:

Main class that schedules the job:

```
public class NotificationScheduler {

private SchedulerFactory sf;
private Scheduler scheduler;

@PostConstruct
public void initNotificationScheduler() {
    try {
    sf = new StdSchedulerFactory("spring/quartz.properties");
    scheduler = sf.getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
            // test out sending a notification at startup, prepare some parameters...
    this.scheduleImmediateNotificationJob(messageParameters, recipients);
        try {
            // wait 20 seconds to show jobs
            logger.info("sleeping...");
            Thread.sleep(40L * 1000L); 
            logger.info("finished sleeping");
           // executing...
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }

      } catch (SchedulerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException("NotificationScheduler failed to retrieve a Scheduler instance: ", e);
    }
}


public void scheduleImmediateNotificationJob(){
  try {
    JobKey jobKey = new JobKey("key");
    Date fireTime = DateBuilder.futureDate(delayInSeconds, IntervalUnit.SECOND);
    JobDetail emailJob = JobBuilder.newJob(EMailJob.class)
    .withIdentity(jobKey.toString(), "immediateEmailsGroup")
        .build();

    TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("triggerKey");
    SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger() 
        .withIdentity(triggerKey.toString(), "immediateEmailsGroup")
        .startAt(fireTime)
        .build();

    // schedule the job to run
    Date scheduleTime1 = scheduler.scheduleJob(emailJob, trigger);
  } catch (SchedulerException e) {
    logger.error("error scheduling job: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
}

@PreDestroy
public void cleanup(){
    sf = null;
    try {
        scheduler.shutdown();
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The EmailJob is the same as in my first posting except for the @Component annotation:

```
@Component
public class EMailJob implements Job { 
  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl;
... }
```

And the Spring's configuration file has:

```
...
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/*.properties" />
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mybasepackage">
  <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
        type="annotation" />
</context:component-scan>
<bean id="mailSenderImpl" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.host}"/>
    <property name="port" value="${mail.port}"/>
    ...
</bean>
<bean id="notificationScheduler" class="com.mybasepackage.notifications.NotificationScheduler">
</bean>
```

Thanks for all the help!

Marina

Comment: When your app starts up, do you see `EmailJob` being initialized?  An easy way to check is to add a log line in the constructor.

Comment: @Aaron: yes, I do - but as I just discovered, it is being initialized twice! Once by the Spring framework itself (and I bet this instance has the mail service injected into it...) and then, later, after the Quartz itself is initialized - the EMailJob is getting initialized again by the Quartz framework - and that's the one that does not have the service injected... I will try to add a stack trace of the Spring's startup by editing my question , as Ryan suggested...

Answer (score 3):

This is a quite an old post which is still useful. All the solutions that proposes these two had little condition that not suite all:

- `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` This assumes or requires it to be a spring - web based project
- `AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory` based approach mentioned in previous answer is very helpful, but the answer is specific to those who don't use pure vanilla quartz api but rather Spring's wrapper for the quartz to do the same.

**If you want to remain with pure Quartz implementation for scheduling(Quartz with Autowiring capabilities with Spring), I was able to do it as follows:**

I was looking to do it quartz way as much as possible and thus little hack proves helpful.

```
 public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory{

    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    public AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory(final ApplicationContext applicationContext){
        beanFactory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        beanFactory.initializeBean(job, job.getClass().getName());
        return job;
    }
}


@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {   
    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory getAutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory(){
        return new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory(applicationContext);
    }
}


private void initializeAndStartScheduler(final Properties quartzProperties)
            throws SchedulerException {
        //schedulerFactory.initialize(quartzProperties);
        Scheduler quartzScheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

        //Below one is the key here. Use the spring autowire capable job factory and inject here
        quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(autowiringSpringBeanJobFactory);
        quartzScheduler.start();
    }
```

`quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(autowiringSpringBeanJobFactory);` gives us an autowired job instance. Since `AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory` implicitly implements a `JobFactory`, we now enabled an auto-wireable solution. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

A solution from Hary https://stackoverflow.com/a/37797575/4252764 works very well. It's simpler, doesn't need so many special factory beans, and support multiple triggers and jobs.
Would just add that Quartz job can be made to be generic, with specific jobs implemented as regular Spring beans.

```
public interface BeanJob {
  void executeBeanJob();
}

public class GenericJob implements Job {

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobDataMap dataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
    ((BeanJob)dataMap.get("beanJob")).executeBeanJob();    
  }

}

@Component
public class RealJob implements BeanJob {
  private SomeService service;

  @Autowired
  public RealJob(SomeService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public void executeBeanJob() {
      //do do job with service
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I considered that too. But in my case, I was writing a library that abstracts any quartz implementation. This required for remembering the 'key' name to retrieve any objects. I was able to do it pure quartz way and just posted it as an answer. Pls share your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it would be to just annotate the Quartz Jobs with `@Component` annotation, and then Spring will do all the DI magic for you, as it is now recognized as a Spring bean.  I had to do something similar for an `AspectJ` aspect - it was not a Spring bean until I annotated it with the Spring `@Component` stereotype.

Comment: Thanks,Aaron, I just tried  - but unfortunately the same NPE happens - and the mail service is not getting injected into the job bean...

Comment: Is your `EmailJob` class in a package which would be scanned by Spring on app startup?  The fact that you annotated with `@Component` but the injected class is still null indicates that its not being scanned - otherwise the DI at app startup would throw an exception.

Comment: Aaron: yes, it is supposed to be scanned  - I have the <context:component-scan base-package="com.mybasepackage"> that should do it... In my next answer I am providing a full code of my main class, with the Spring configuration - just in case something obvious can be spotted...

Comment: The job fields marked with "@Autowired" are not injected even if you mark the Job with "@Component"

Comment: This will not work because creating Job objects are managed by quarts and therefore fields is not autowired and class annotations does nothing without extra handling.

Answer (score 1):

The solution above is great but in my case the injection was not working. I needed to use autowireBeanProperties instead, probably due to the way my context is configured:

```java
import org.quartz.spi.TriggerFiredBundle;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory;

public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements
ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        //beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(job, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
        return job;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990767/inject-bean-reference-into-a-quartz-job-in-spring/15211030#15211030. and will work for most of the folks. But if your web.xml does is not aware of all applicationContext.xml files, quartz job will not be able to invoke those beans. I had to do an extra layer to inject additional applicationContext files

```
public class MYSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory
        implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private transient AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {

        try {
                PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pmrl = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(context.getClassLoader());
                Resource[] resources = new Resource[0];
                GenericApplicationContext createdContext = null ;
                    resources = pmrl.getResources(
                            "classpath*:my-abc-integration-applicationContext.xml"
                    );

                    for (Resource r : resources) {
                        createdContext = new GenericApplicationContext(context);
                        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(createdContext);
                        int i = reader.loadBeanDefinitions(r);
                    }

            createdContext.refresh();//important else you will get exceptions.
            beanFactory = createdContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    @Override
    protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle)
            throws Exception {
        final Object job = super.createJobInstance(bundle);
        beanFactory.autowireBean(job);
        return job;
    }
}
```

You can add any number of context files you want your quartz to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Simply extend your job from `QuartzJobBean`

```
public class MyJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    @Autowired
    private SomeBean someBean;

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Some bean is " + someBean.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your

```
AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory
```

dependency is pulled from

```
    "org.springframework:spring-context-support:4..."
```

and NOT from

```
    "org.springframework:spring-support:2..."
```

It wanted me to use

```
@Override
public Job newJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, Scheduler scheduler)
```

instead of

```
@Override
protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle)
```

so was failing to autowire job instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you already use real AspectJ in your project, then you could annotate the job bean class with `@Configurable`. Then Spring will inject into this class, even if it is constructed via `new`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similiar problem and came out from it with following approach:

```
<!-- Quartz Job -->
<bean name="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <!-- <constructor-arg ref="dao.DAOFramework" /> -->
     <property name="jobDataAsMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="daoBean" value-ref="dao.DAOFramework" />
    </map>
</property>
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.stratasync.jobs.JobA" />
    <property name="durability" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

In above code I inject dao.DAOFramework bean into JobA bean and in inside ExecuteInternal method you can get injected bean like:

```
  daoFramework = (DAOFramework)context.getMergedJobDataMap().get("daoBean");
```

I hope it helps! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All those solutions above doesn't work for me with Spring 5 and Hibernate 5 and Quartz 2.2.3 when I want to call transactional methods!

I therefore implemented this solution which automatically starts the scheduler and triggers the jobs. I found a lot of that code at [dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-and-quartz-integration-that-works-together). Because I don't need to create triggers and jobs dynamically I wanted the static triggers to be pre defined via Spring Configuration and only the jobs to be exposed as Spring Components.

My basic configuration look like this

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler(@Autowired JobFactory jobFactory) throws IOException {
    SchedulerFactoryBean sfb = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

    sfb.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
    sfb.setAutoStartup(true);
    sfb.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    Trigger[] triggers = new Trigger[] {
        cronTriggerTest().getObject()
    };
    sfb.setTriggers(triggers);
    return sfb;
  }

  @Bean
  public JobFactory cronJobFactory() {
    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return jobFactory;
  }

  @Bean 
  public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerTest() {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean tfb = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    tfb.setCronExpression("0 * * ? * * *");

    JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(CronTest.class)
                            .withIdentity("Testjob")
                            .build()
                            ;

    tfb.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    return tfb;
  }

}
```

As you can see, you have the scheduler and a simple test trigger which is defined via a cron expression. You can obviously choose whatever scheduling expression you like. You then need the AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory which goes like this

```
public final class AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory extends SpringBeanJobFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  private SchedulerContext schedulerContext;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext context) {
    this.applicationContext = context;
  }


  @Override
  protected Object createJobInstance(final TriggerFiredBundle bundle) throws Exception {
    Job job = applicationContext.getBean(bundle.getJobDetail().getJobClass());
    BeanWrapper bw = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(job);

    MutablePropertyValues pvs = new MutablePropertyValues();
    pvs.addPropertyValues(bundle.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap());
    pvs.addPropertyValues(bundle.getTrigger().getJobDataMap());

    if (this.schedulerContext != null)
    {
        pvs.addPropertyValues(this.schedulerContext);
    }
    bw.setPropertyValues(pvs, true);

    return job;
  }  

  public void setSchedulerContext(SchedulerContext schedulerContext) {
    this.schedulerContext = schedulerContext;
    super.setSchedulerContext(schedulerContext);
  }

}
```

In here you wire your normal application context and your job together. This is the important gap because normally Quartz starts it's worker threads which have no connection to your application context. That is the reason why you can't execute Transactional mehtods. The last thing missing is a job. It can look like that

```
@Component
public class CronTest implements Job {

  @Autowired
  private MyService s;

  public CronTest() {
  }

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    s.execute();
  }

}
```

It's not a perfect solution because you an extra class only for calling your service method. But nevertheless it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Jdbc jobstore**

If you are using jdbc jobstore Quartz uses a different classloader. That prevents all the workarounds for autowiring, since objects from spring will not be compatible at quartz side, because they originited from a different class loader.

To fix that, the default classloader has to be set in the quartz properties file like this:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class=org.quartz.simpl.ThreadContextClassLoadHelper
```

As reference:
https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/issues/221