# Pointcut expression is not working with Custom Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, spring-aop, pointcut

I have following **Custom Annotation**.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Scheduled {
    String cron() default "";
    .....
```

**Implementation** class

```
@Named
public class JobDefination {
@Scheduled(concurrent = false, cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    public void removeHistory(){
            .....
}
```

**The Aspect**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectImple {
@Before("@annotation(com.quartzConfiguration.Scheduled)")
        public void beforeImplAnnotation() {
              ...
        }
@Before("execution(* com.job.defination.JobDefination.*()) && @annotation(com.quartzConfiguration.Scheduled)")
        public void beforeImpl2() {
            ...
        }
```

I have tried with above pointcut one by one. But AOP not working when when quartz calling the method. Could someone please help.

Comment: Two notes: Spring has a `@Scheduled` annotation. It's definition, not defination. Is your annotated object managed by spring?

Comment: No, this annotated Object is our custom implementation

Comment: I meant "Does Spring control the lifecycle of the object? Does it create it?" It needs to create a Proxy for it to be advised.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis : Sorry for delayed replied. Log suggests Spring is controlling the life-cycle of this bean and also creating proxy but failing to apply any advised on the method. .. Some log snaps AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator - Creating implicit proxy for bean 'jobDefination' with 0 common interceptors and 5 specif ic interceptors....... Cglib2AopProxy - Unable to apply any optimisations to advised method: public void com.job.defination.JobDefination.removeHistory()

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the quartz jobs are created within the spring context. There is already a question covering that topic here: [inject bean reference into a Quartz job in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990767/inject-bean-reference-into-a-quartz-job-in-spring)