# Using PersistenceContext in a Quartz Job

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, quartz-scheduler

We're using Spring 3.1, JPA (via Hibernate) and Quartz.  Typically we interact with the DB via @PersistenceContext annotation on Service beans, and either SpringMVC controllers, or GraniteDS-managed service invocation.

I'm working on writing a Quartz job that needs to interact with the database.  I've tried everything I can find to get this working.  I tried passing in a Spring-managed component (annotated with @PersistenceContext and @Transactional) via the jobMap, the call to entityManager.persist(o) executes, but nothing happens in the database.  I also tried similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211030/2280576), creating a factory class to call autowireBean() on the job object.  I set up the job class like so:

```
public class CreateAlertJob implements Job {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
}
```

Same result, the method executes but the database is unaltered.  I found [this blog post](http://blog.tirasa.net/blogs/index.php/ilgrosso/aop-n-spring-n-jpa) which references a GitHub project.  There he is using JpaInterceptor to establish a Hibernate session, but this uses the DAO pattern and I'd like to stick with using @PersistenceContext.

Clearly there is something about the Quartz thread that is preventing this from working properly?  I'm about out of ideas and considering making a web service call to a SpringMVC controller just to get this working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your `CreateAlertJob` is not created by Spring, `@Transactional` in it doesn't take effect.

You have the following options:

- Delegate actual work to Spring bean and put `@Transactional` there
- Use [programmatic transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-programmatic)
- [Use AspectJ-based AOP implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead of Spring default implementation (but it would be overkill for such a simple problem)

Comment: I had tried this initially and it wasn't working but it's clear there are some other issues going on.  Doing the work in a Spring bean seems to best option, and is working well.