# Spring scheduled-tasks datasource

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks, datasource, applicationcontext

I want to make applicationContext inside scheduler method. it is possible ? )

```
 <task:annotation-driven executor="executor" scheduler="scheduler"/>
 <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5"/>
 <task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="10"/>
```

And my class :

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=100)
public void doSomething() {

}
```

How me add that ? :

```
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {

    this.applicationContext = applicationContext; 
}
```

That use it code :

```
JDBCEntityDAO obj = (JDBCEntityDAO) applicationContext.getBean("taEntityDAO");
```

Help please

Answer (score 3):

Just add @Autowired or any other dependency injection annotation to your job classes (the ones with @Scheduled - annotated methods). If you need a reference to the ApplicationContext, make your job implement the ApplicationContextAware interface.
This will work with the Spring native scheduler.
If you use Quartz, you'll have to do a little more work, see here [inject bean reference into a Quartz job in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990767/inject-bean-reference-into-a-quartz-job-in-spring) .
By the way, you can use @Resourse annotation to inject beans by name.