# Quartz does not support @autowired

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am implement a Quartz job using a DAO service as below:

```
public class InitialFetchFrequenceScheduleJob implements Job
{
    @Autowired
    private FetchFrequencyService fetchFrequencyService;

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
    {
        try
        {
            List<FetchFrequency> frequencies = this.fetchFrequencyService.findAll(FetchFrequency.class);
```

The problem is, when call execute() method, the `this.fetchFrequencyService.findAll(FetchFrequency.class);` will throw NPE because fetchFrequenceService is null. I do anything wrong here? Any reply is much appreciated. Thank you!

P/s I am using Quartz 2.1.7

Update: This is FetchFrequencyServiceImpl:

```
@Service("fetchFrequencyService")
public class FetchFrequencyServiceImpl extends GenericDaoImpl implements FetchFrequencyService
{
}
```

Update: The code implement job:

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(InitialFetchFrequenceScheduleJob.class).build();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(job).startAt(cal.getTime()).build();
        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties").getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to integrate Spring with Quartz?

Answer (score 7):

`@Autowired` will not work in a Quartz job implementation because it will not be instantiated by Spring. In order to get hold of Spring-managed beans in a Quartz job you should first of all use `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean` to manage the Quartz lifecycle. Using this FactoryBean you can specify the `applicationContextSchedulerContextKey` property to have a reference to the ApplicationContext supplied to your Quartz job in the scheduler context, e.g.:

```
<bean id="scheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    <!-- additional properties here -->
</bean>
```

You can now retrieve the `ApplicationContext` reference in your job, and then explicitly get the bean reference from the `ApplicationContext`:

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) executionContext
               .getScheduler().getContext().get("applicationContext");

    FetchFrequencyService service = applicationContext.getBean(FetchFrequencyService.class);

    // Start using your service.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find applicationContext.getBean() method. I am using spring 4.0.6

Comment: ApplicationContext.getBean is still present in 4.x (defined in interface BeanFactory, which is inherited by ApplicationContext).

Comment: I did an edit on your code executionContext. It needs review from peer. You have JobExecutionContext context instead of JobExecutionContext executionContext

Comment: @hfk: The edit is correct: the original code doesn't compile, since the parameter is named context but I'm referring to executionContext in the method body.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using Quartz does not get Spring involved in the process at all, and therefor no wiring of dependencies takes place.

I suggest you take a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) part of the official documentation for the basic info on how to integrate Spring with Quartz as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15211030/2504224) great SO answer

Comment: thanks, but i want create Trigger dynamically not configure in xml file.

Comment: @doxuannam Good point! I am sure you could hack your way around the code and get it to work with dynamic triggers as well

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectBasedOnCurrentContext(this)
```

to autowire your beans in your quartz job

Answer (score -1):

you have to annotate your classes with either of following annotation

for DAO

> @Repository

service

> @Service

controlloer

> @Controller

so your service class should have below annotation.

```
@Service("fetchFrequencyService")
public Class FetchFrequencyService {
}
```

i thing you need to inject application context into SchedulerFactoryBean

```
<bean id="scheduler"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="false">
        <property name="jobFactory">
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
            <value>applicationContext</value>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I've updated the FetchFrequenceServiceImpl class

Comment: are you still getting NPE

Comment: yes, I added @Repository to FetchFrequenceServiceImpl class too, but NPE still happens :(