# Spring @Autowired beans are null - how to find the mistake

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I integrated Spring batch and the quartz timer into my Spring-MVC application. Currently I have several directories:

`@Autowire` works everywhere but in MyBatchJob.java (-> code compiles but properties are NULL during runtime)

```
- batch
    +- MyProcessor
    +- MyReader
    +- MyWriter
    +- MyListener
- config
    +- MainConfig
    +- BatchConfig
- controller
[...]
- schedule
    +- MyBatchJob
```

BatchConfig is annotated with:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.backend.schedule")
@EnableBatchProcessing // imports jobLauncher, stepBuilderFactory, jobBuilderFactory, ...
public class BatchConfig {

    @Bean
    public JobDetail jobDetail() {
        return newJob(MyBatchJob.class)
            .withIdentity("name", "group")
            .build();
    }
```

and imported in MainConfig using `@Import(BatchConfig.class)`. In this configuration file and in the controllers I can `@Autowire` the classes I need. But it does not work in my my.backend.schedule.MyBatchJob class:

```
@Component
public class MyBatchJob implements org.quartz.Job {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher; // null

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory; // null

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory; // null
```

What is the reason for this, how can I find and fix it?

Meta: I already searched a lot and saw many threads here on SO - but did not find the solution. I already know how the spring beans live inside the container but that does not give me the answer - I may overlook something.

edit: additional information as requested inserted into BatchConfig class above.

edit2: Changing to JobDetailFactoryBean:

BatchConfig:

```
@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    factory.setJobClass(MyBatchJob.class);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public Trigger myJobTrigger() throws Exception {

    SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();

    Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("mySynchTrigger", "synch")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                .withIntervalInSeconds(30) // testing
                .repeatForever())
            .build();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetailFactory().getObject(), trigger);
    return trigger;
}
```

Comment: How do you retrieve and use your `MyBatchJob` bean?

Comment: Inside the BatchConfig I create a `JobDetail`-Bean using `JobBuilder.newJob`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Please show us. Edit your question.

Comment: yes. you should always use @Autowired for all beans. new operator will cause issues to autowired

Comment: I do not use the new operator but the JobBuilder.newJob method of the quartz framework returning a static JobBuilder.

Comment: What does `newJob` do? What does the `build` method return?

Comment: Better than an own word explanation: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobBuilder.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990767/inject-bean-reference-into-a-quartz-job-in-spring

Comment: I suspect a different instance is being used. Instantiating with `new` isn't a problem for an `@Bean`; Spring autowires them.

Comment: The `JobDetailFactoryBean` creates a new instance of `MyBatchJob`. It doesn't use the Spring bean. Why don't you just use `@Scheduled` instead of this rather complex setup?

Answer (score 0):

You should register a [JobDetailFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/JobDetailFactoryBean.html) as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) rather than using the Quartz API yourself.

Comment: I changed the BatchConfig as in the question above (using the JobDetailFactoryBean), jobLauncher still remains NULL. Maybe the documentation is outdated as it is still xml only?