# How do I invoke a method on an existing object with Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a object, nicely configured with everything it needs to do its job. If I could just call `run()` on it once a day, my life would be complete.

To be clear, I know how to create a schedule and a trigger. But the methods to schedule all take JobDetail, which wants to create a new instance of my class. How do I use the one that I have?

In short, is there a nice way without Spring to call a method on my object using Quartz?

Comment: I don't know if you are using some framework to run your object and the scheduled Quartz jobs like Spring. Let's asume that you aren't. What about using the Singleton pattern to recover an instance of your object?

Comment: Spring has MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean. Another option may be creating job class that take your object (from job data or something) and call it.

Comment: If you are using Spring, there are a lot of possible solutions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990767/inject-bean-reference-into-a-quartz-job-in-spring

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Quartz with Spring you can do the following :

[Sample code](https://github.com/m4ver1k/scheduler)

```
 MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailfactory = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
 jobDetailfactory.setTargetObject(configuredObject);
 jobDetailfactory.setTargetMethod("methodName");
```

Here `configuredObject` is your nicely configured object  and `methodName` is the name of the method to be invoked. You can autowire the configuredObject into this class.

Comment: But OP do not want to get a new instance of his object/helper

Comment: Ah, sorry, don't want to pull in all (or TBH any) of Spring.

Comment: If I don't want to use any framework, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quartz JobBuilder to build Quartz JobDetail Object using your own jobDetails class, if I get you correctly. let me know if it is not required by you.

Suppose Job info is your own class having jobdetails. then you can use it below like this:

JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();

```
Map<String, Object> jobParams = jobInfo.getJobParams();
for (String paramKey : jobParams.keySet()) {
  jobDataMap.put(paramKey, jobParams.get(paramKey));
}

jobBuilder.ofType((Class<? extends Job>) Class.forName(jobInfo.getJobClass()))
    .withIdentity(jobInfo.getName(), jobInfo.getGroup())
    .withDescription(jobInfo.getDescription()).storeDurably(jobInfo.isStoreDurably())
    .usingJobData(jobDataMap);

JobDetail jobDetail = jobBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code (Kotlin)

```
fun createJobDetail(jobName: String, function: () -> Unit)  = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob::class.java)
    .withIdentity(jobName)
    .usingJobData(JobDataMap(mapOf(jobDataKey to function)))
    .build()`

@DisallowConcurrentExecution
class MyJob : Job {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun execute(context: JobExecutionContext) {
        try {
            (context.jobDetail.jobDataMap[jobDataKey] as () -> Unit)()
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            throw JobExecutionException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Quartz, you might be better off using the built-in `java.util.concurrent.` `ScheduledExecutorService` and its `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method.

For example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1,
        new ThreadFactory() {

            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
                Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(runnable);
                t.setDaemon(true);
                return t;
            }
        });


scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myLovelyObject.run();
        }
    }, 0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

If you need to use Quartz, you could always store a reference to your object in a static field in the Job class. Not elegant, but not exactly the end of the world either.

Comment: It's the cron pattern parsing that I need!

Comment: Take a look at [`org.quartz.CronExpression`](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/CronExpression.java). The cron pattern parsing is entirely self-contained. You could even just copy that one class into your project.