# @Autowired Component inside Quartz Job in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am facing a problem with Quartz and Spring implementation.
When I autowire a component inside a Quartz Job I got this error:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127) ~[quartz-2.2.3.jar:na]
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375) [quartz-2.2.3.jar:na]Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.kaloudia.api.quartz.jobs.ArticlePublicationJob
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.createJobInstance(AdaptableJobFactory.java:58) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41) ~[spring-context-support-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 2 common frames omittedCaused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.kaloudia.api.quartz.jobs.ArticlePublicationJob.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
... 4 common frames omitted
```

I use the @Autowired annotation in order to get an instance of the BlogManager but when debuge my code I can see that this variable is null.
Do you have any idea, how can I get BlogManager class inside the Quartz Job class?

My Job Class:

```
@Service
public class ArticlePublicationJob implements Job {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ArticlePublicationJob.class);
public static final String ARTICLE_ID = "ARTICLE_ID";

private final BlogManager blogManager;

@Autowired
public ArticlePublicationJob(BlogManager blogManager) {
    this.blogManager = blogManager;
}

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    JobDataMap data = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    Integer articleId = data.getInt(ARTICLE_ID);
    blogManager.actionOnArticle(articleId, "publish", 0);
}
}
```

and my Quartz Manager:

```
public class QuartzManager {

private final SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

@Inject
public QuartzManager(SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean) {
    this.schedulerFactoryBean = schedulerFactoryBean;
}

public void schedulePublishArticleTrigger(Integer articleId, java.util.Calendar publishDate) throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler sched = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ArticlePublicationJob.class)
            .withIdentity("article_" + articleId, "blog").build();
    job.getJobDataMap().put(ArticlePublicationJob.ARTICLE_ID, articleId);
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("PublishArticle_" + articleId, "blog")
            .startAt(publishDate.getTime())
            .forJob("article_" + articleId, "blog")
            .build();
    sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of `BlogManager`? Is it a Spring-managed component?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990767/inject-bean-reference-into-a-quartz-job-in-spring/15211030#15211030?

Comment: @rperes 
Yes, it's a spring component. 
I have some methods for Blog Management.