# How to retain the instance variables passed to Quartz job ever after webserver restart?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz scheduler in java web application.
My question is an extension to [How to pass instance variables into Quartz job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777057/how-to-pass-instance-variables-into-quartz-job)

I followed the Accepted answer in the above post & could pass instance variable to my quartz job. But after restarting the web server, the passed instance variable is not retained (i.e., it is null)

```
public class SimpleJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        SchedulerContext schedulerContext = null;
        try {
            schedulerContext = context.getScheduler().getContext();
        } catch (SchedulerException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ExternalInstance externalInstance =
            (ExternalInstance) schedulerContext.get("ExternalInstance");

        System.out.println(externalInstance); //Will print "null" after web server restart

        float avg = externalInstance.calculateAvg();
    }
}
```

How can I retain the "ExternalInstance" even after web server restart?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) to your web project, and on `contextInitialized()`, you can put the `externalInstance` in the `SchedulerContext`. That way, it will be loaded every time the server restarts.